# Reverse Image Loop

Tags: jquery, image, loops, gallery

Ok so I found a script on the internet, i forgot the source.

but basically for every time an image is clicked it moves forward down the list hides and then shows an image.

I have since modified it EXTENSIVELY!

However it gets stuck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var count = $('.image_news').length;
$("#total").text(count);
$('.image_news:gt(0)').hide();

var $slides = $('.image_news');

$slides.click(function () {
    var $current = $(this);
    if ($current.is($slides.last())) {
        $("#current").text("1");
        $current.hide();
        $slides.first().fadeIn(1000).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#current").text($current.next().index()+1);
        $current.hide().next().fadeIn(1000).show();
    }
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var count = $('.image_news').length;
$("#total").text(count);
$('.image_news:gt(0)').hide();

var $slides = $('.image_news');
var $backarrow = $('.back-arrow');
$backarrow.click(function () {
    var $current = $slides;
    if ($current.is($slides.first())) {
        $("#current").text(count);
        $current.hide();
        $slides.last().fadeIn(1000).show();
    }  else if (!$($current.is($slides.last()))) {
        $("#current").text($current.prev().index()-1);
        $current.hide().prev().fadeIn(1000).show();
        } else {

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I assigned a new image to check to see where we are at in the loop, but after the first click it gets stuck!

Relooping back.

I cant for the life of me figure out where my logic errors are...

here is the active page:

http://www.gluzio.com

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

G

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, I can click through all 6 images on your site.

Comment: forward yes. reverse, no =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$backarrow.click(function () {
    var $current = $slides;
```

wants to be:

```
$backarrow.click(function () {
    var $current = $slides.filter(':visible:first');
```

Comment: gluzio.com    It is working in reverse now but it jumps a bit. I am going to see why. YOURE A FRIKKIN GENIUS!!!!!

Comment: I had to also modify:             $("#current").text($current.prev().index()-1);
$current.hide().prev().fadeIn(1000).show();          to                $("#current").text($current.next().index()-1);
            $current.hide().prev().fadeIn(1000).show();

Comment: You're most welcome, Giuseppe. Your website looks great.